# Como guardo en otra base de datos el resultado de la tabla que me muestra el php

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, gps

Estoy dando vueltas con esto, recién empiezo a programar y no puedo solucionar el guardado en otra base de datos la consulta que me muestra la siguiente tabla. Es decir que quiero guardar en otra base de datos el resultado que me da la consulta. =(

```php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Bucaramanga Coordinates
    $lat=-34.6468344;
    $lng=-58.4867486;


        
    // Only show places within 100km
    $distance = 0.25;

    $lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $lat);
    $lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $lng);
    $distance = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $distance);

    $query = <<<EOF SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,(((acos(sin(( $lat * pi() / 180))*sin(( `lat` * pi() / 180)) + cos(( $lat * pi() /180 ))*cos(( `lat` * pi() / 180)) * cos((( $lng - `lng`) * pi()/180)))) * 180/pi()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344)as distance FROM `gps` ORDER BY id DESC) gps WHERE distance <= $distance LIMIT 15; EOF;

    $result = $conn->query($query);
  
echo '<table class="table" style="font-size:12px; margin-top:-1%;">
                <tr class="active">
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Coordinador</th>
                    <th>Objetivo</th>
                    <th>Latitud</th>
                    <th>Longitud</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                </tr>';
                
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
            echo'<tr>
                 <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['coord'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['obj'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['lat'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['lng'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['fecha'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['hora'].'</td>
                 </tr>';
        }echo '</table>';
    }
```

Comment: Lo lógico sería: 1. Conectar a la base de datos A, lanzar la consulta, recuperar los datos y guardarlos en una variable. 2. Conectar a la base de datos B, y usar los datos obtenidos en (1) para insertarlos en la base de datos B. Si el usuario tiene permisos para ambas bases de datos puedes hacerlo desde una sola conexión (aunque no lo he probado, debería funcionar)  y puedes hacer el insert con una sub-consulta, algo así: `INSERT INTO dbB.tablaB (colM, colN) VALUES (SELECt colX, colY FROM dbA.tablaA WHERE unaColunma=unCriterio)`

Comment: ¿Quieres guardar el html en la otra base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo pude solucionar asi. Pero creo que debe haber una manera mas facil de harcelo.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


////Inicializas las variables
$var1 = [];
$var2 = [];
$var3 = [];
$var4 = [];
$var5 = [];
$var6 = [];
$var7 = [];



// Bucaramanga Coordinates
$latc=-34.6050386;
$lngc=-58.3801639;


    
// Only show places within 100km
$distance = 0.25;

$latc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $latc);
$lngc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $lngc);
$distance = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $distance);

$query = <<<EOF
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        (
            (
                (
                    acos(
                        sin(( $latc * pi() / 180))
                        *
                        sin(( `lat` * pi() / 180)) + cos(( $latc * pi() /180 ))
                        *
                        cos(( `lat` * pi() / 180)) * cos((( $lngc - `lng`) * pi()/180)))
                ) * 180/pi()
            ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
        )
    as distance FROM `gps` ORDER BY id DESC
) gps
WHERE distance <= $distance
LIMIT 15;
EOF;

$result = $conn->query($query);
        

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        
                     $var1 =$row["id"];
                     $var2 =$row["coord"];
                     $var3 =$row["obj"];
                     $var4 =$row["lat"];
                     $var5 =$row["lng"];
                     $var6 =$row["fecha"];
                     $var7 =$row["hora"];
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO gps1 (id, coord, obj, lat, lng, fecha, hora) VALUES ('$var1', '$var2', '$var3', '$var4', '$var5', '$var6', '$var7')");
     
    }
}

?>
```